# How to Parse an XML file with Linq Lambda from Given Key

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an xml document with Linq and Lambda expression, but need help.

The Node from within which I want to get data is "DiskDriveInfo" ,
I'm also not sure as to how to proceed with the next node "ResultCode i:nil="true" "

My Code:

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(InXML);
var r = from x in xml.Elements("DiskDriveInfo")
                select new
                {
                    ResultCode = x.Element("ResultCode").Value,
                    ResultCodeDescription = 
                          x.Element("ResultCodeDescription").Value,
                    AirbagDetails = x.Element("AirbagDetails").Value,
                    ..
                    ..
                    WheelBase        = x.Element("WheelBase").Value              
};
```

and the input is :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Body>
    <GetConvergedDataRequestResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://autoinsight.trn.co.za/types">
      <ConvergedData xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.orgB2B.BusinessModels" i:type="ConvergedResults">
        <AccidentHistory i:nil="true" />
        <AlertInfo i:nil="true" />
        <CloneInfo i:nil="true" />
        <DiskDriveInfo>
          <ResultCode i:nil="true" />
          <ResultCodeDescription i:nil="true" />
          <AirbagDetails>DRIVER, PASSENGER</AirbagDetails>
...
...
<WheelBase>2460</WheelBase>
    </DiskDriveInfo>
```

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- Your elements are in the namespace "http://autoinsight.trn.co.za/types" but you're looking for them without specifying a namespace
- You're using `xml.Elements` which will only look for root elements; to look for any descendants, you should use `Descendants`.

So you probably want:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://autoinsight.trn.co.za/types";
var xml = XDocument.Parse(InXML);
var r = from x in xml.Descendants(ns + "DiskDriveInfo")
        select new
        {
            ResultCode = x.Element(ns + "ResultCode").Value,
            ResultCodeDescription = x.Element(ns + "ResultCodeDescription").Value,
            AirbagDetails = x.Element(ns + "AirbagDetails").Value,
            ..
            ..
            WheelBase = x.Element(ns + "WheelBase").Value              
        };
```

As a side note, I probably wouldn't use a query expression for this - I'd just call `Select` directly:

```
var r = xml
    .Descendants(ns + "DiskDriveInfo")
    .Select(x => new
    {
        ResultCode = x.Element(ns + "ResultCode").Value,
        ResultCodeDescription = x.Element(ns + "ResultCodeDescription").Value,
        AirbagDetails = x.Element(ns + "AirbagDetails").Value,
        ..
        ..
        WheelBase = x.Element(ns + "WheelBase").Value              
    });
```

If you need an element with `i:nil="true"` to return null instead of an empty string, I'd add an extension method for `XElement`:

```
private static XNamespace SchemaNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
public static string ValueOrNull(this XElement element)
{
    XAttribute nil = element.Attribute(SchemaNamespace + "nil");
    return (string) nil == "true" ? null : element.Value;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://autoinsight.trn.co.za/types";
var xml = XDocument.Parse(InXML);
var r = from x in xml.Descendants(ns + "DiskDriveInfo")
        select new
        {
            ResultCode = x.Element(ns + "ResultCode").ValueOrNull(),
            ResultCodeDescription = x.Element(ns + "ResultCodeDescription").ValueOrNull(),
            AirbagDetails = x.Element(ns + "AirbagDetails").ValueOrNull(),
            ..
            ..
            WheelBase = x.Element(ns + "WheelBase").ValueOrNull()             
        };
```

Comment: Good answer. Just to clarify. `x.Element(...).Value` will give the value `string.Empty`. But given `nil="true"` it should be `null`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Um, maybe? That wasn't in the requirements in the question. Will edit something into the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You can write from below code just you need to create class according to you xml file and below is function to convert directly xml to class object

```
    public T DeserializeData(string dataXML)
    {
         XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
         xDoc.LoadXml(dataXML);
         XmlNodeReader xNodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xDoc.DocumentElement);
         XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
         var modelData = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xNodeReader);
         T deserializedModel = (T)modelData ;
         return deserializedModel;
    }
```